# How to set different input sizes in an input-group?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have several input/buttons in a single input-group. I'd also like the first input to be smaller than the other one. For now, it re-sizes the input but the other element stay in place, creating a gap.

What am I missing?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-exclamation"></i></span>
    <input style="width:150px" type="text" class="form-control" name="command">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment"></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="update"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i></button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding div with classes like col-xs-6 in every inputs

Comment: Encapsulating everything add lots of margin and kind of break the input-group.

Comment: You wanted to remove the gap between inputs right?

Comment: I want the comment icon to be close to the left input, with the left input keeping its size and the right input expanding to compensate.